# Force https+www in WordPress and non-WordPress subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to force https and www with `.htaccess`, and I'm looking for a solution that is not domain-specific, but will apply to any domain and any folder (using server variables).

The setup:

- `domain.com` has WordPress installed
- `domain.com/folder2` is a physical folder and contains a separate site

The .htaccess file in `domain.com` currently contains:

```
# force www+https
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This seems to work for `domain.com`, but not for `domain.com/folder2`: while https is enforced there, the www redirect doesn't work.

I tried placing a second .htaccess file in `domain.com/folder2`; that doesn't do anything either.

Questions:

- How can I make these rules apply to `domain.com/folder2` as well?
- I've kept the WordPress block separate because WordPress would probably duplicate it when e.g. permalinks are changed via admin, and it doesn't find this block as-is. Is this correct, or is there a better way to consolidate the two blocks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In .htaccess in /folder2, add the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Delete your /folder2/.htaccess if you want to place this in your root dir.